# Adding functions to class which have access to instance variables

Tags: python

I have a function that takes some data and organizes it into different containers. This is accomplished by different parsers for different input data.

```
class ParsingObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.organized_data_1 = OrganizedContainer1()
        self.organized_data_2 = OrganizedContainer2()
        self.organized_data_3 = OrganizedContainer3()

    def parse_data(format, data):
        if format == 'format1':
            # Some code that takes data, and populate containers
            self.organized_data_1 = x
            self.organized_data_2 = y
            self.organized_data_3 = z
        if format == 'format2':
            # Some code that takes data, and populate containers differently
            self.organized_data_1 = y
            self.organized_data_2 = z
            self.organized_data_3 = x
```

I would like to store all the parsers in a separate file and then import them into the parse_data function.

The function needs to have access to the instance variables (organized_data_1-3) in order to populate them.

```
class ParsingObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.organized_data_1 = OrganizedContainer1()
        self.organized_data_2 = OrganizedContainer2()
        self.organized_data_3 = OrganizedContainer3()

    def parse_data(format, data):
        import .parsers
        if format == 'format1': parsers.parser1(data)
        if format == 'format2': parsers.parser2(data)
```

And the parsers something like

```
def parser1(data):
    self.organized_data_1 = x
    self.organized_data_2 = y
    self.organized_data_3 = z
```

I'm looking to put the parsers in another function to make adding additional parsers more convenient and to prevent clutter in main object. Should I just pass the object through to the parser?

```
def parser1(self,data):
    self.organized_data_1 = x
    self.organized_data_2 = y
    self.organized_data_3 = z
```

Or is there another way? If I set it up like this, I end up with circular module imports.

Comment: There are lots of ways to handle this, including subclassing and ordinary functions (which can take the instance and additional arguments and operate on it as `inst.field = whatever` for instance: there's no need for this to be `self.field`).  It would probably help if you [had an mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As @torek said, you could define the parser as `def parser1(inst, data): inst.organized_data_1 = x`, and then call it like that: `if format == 'format1': parsers.parser1(self, data)`